# Iptables fails to redirect traffic to transparent proxy

Tags: iptables, transparent-proxy, socks

My goal was to use ubuntu as a router, with Redsocks serving as a transparent SOCKS proxy redirector. Each machine on my network would have its TCP/UDP traffic redirected to a different port where Redsocks was listening. Example: Machine 1 would have traffic sent to port 12345, and Redsocks would hand that off to external proxy 1. Machine 2 would have traffic sent to port 12346, and Redsocks would send that to proxy 2.

I figured that iptables could handle the initial redirecting to the specific Redsocks port location. I found a case similar to mine where SNAT was employed ([iptables for transparent NAT](https://serverfault.com/questions/106161/iptables-for-transparent-nat)) but cannot get it to work with the following:

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.50:12345
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong with this.

My setup: Router has 2 NICs. Eth0 faces the WAN. Eth1 faces the LAN and has a static IP.

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1

eth0=192.168.1.50

eth1=192.168.50.1

All router clients have one NIC, static IP facing the LAN.
eth1=192.168.50.2

Why I want to do this: I can run Redsocks successfully on the individual machines and transmit via their respective proxies, but I wanted to keep all the routing in one place for the sake of convenience.

Comment: BTW, in your iptables rules, you are never actually sending packets sending anything REDSOCKS chain.  Chains only get processed when you have a rule that jumps to that chain.

Comment: @Zoredache, he is using [REDSOCKS](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/), which transparently redirects traffic to a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need a DNAT rule in the PREROUTING chain and a SNAT rule in the POSTROUTING chain.

Take another look at the [previous serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/106161/iptables-for-transparent-nat) that you linked:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 192.168.250.3 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.4 
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.250.4 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.250.3
```

Additionally, you do not want to set the port on the `--to-source` for the SNAT rule.

You will want to read up on the differences between DNAT and SNAT, [which you can do here](http://www.brennan.id.au/06-Firewall_Concepts.html).

[This document on TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html) may be able to help with this specific scenario.